# Problem with @iota/client npm package in react app

Tags: client-library

I am trying to use  @iota/client package.

But on building react application I get this error:

```
/node_modules/@iota/client/out/lib/Client.js:1:2
1: MZ��!�☺L�!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.
     ^
2: $�uG

error during build:
Error: Unexpected character '�' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (file:////node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
    at Module.error (file:////node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12429:16)
    at Module.tryParse (file:////node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12806:25)
    at Module.setSource (file:////node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:12711:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (file:////node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:21959:20)
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files? Does it help if you delete `node_modules/@iota` and run `npm install` again? Looks like your client.js is an EXE file instead of JavaScript... That does not happen for me.

Answer (score 0):

`@iota/client` is deprecated. Please use the [IOTA SDK](https://wiki.iota.org/iota-sdk/welcome/).

About your error, the library uses WASM, which you will need to provide when using a bundler. See [this guide](https://wiki.iota.org/iota-sdk/getting-started/wasm/) how to do this for Rollup.